# How do I use the Subspace Test?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working through some exercise sheets for uni and for the life of me I can't work out how to do the following question:

For each of the following, either use the subspace test to show that the given subset,
W, is a subspace of V , or explain why the given subset is not a subspace of V .

a. $V = \Bbb{R^3}$ and $W = \{(2t, -t, 3t^2|t \in \Bbb{R^3}\}$

b. $V = \Bbb{R^3}$ and $W = \{(x,y,z) \in V|2x = 3y\}$

c. $V = \mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R^3})$ and $W = \{f \in V|f(-1) = 0\}$

I understand the basics of the test in that I need to prove that the subspace is non-empty, and is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication - but I don't understand how to apply this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example for the first one, let $a,b\in W$, then we have
$$a=(2t,-t,3t^2)$$
$$b=(2s,-s,3s^2)$$
then
$$a+b=(2t+2s,-t-s,3t^2+3s^2)=(2(t+s),-(t+s),3(t^2+s^2))$$
And $t+s\in\Bbb R$ and we have $\sqrt{t^2+s^2}$, however notice that $s+t\neq \sqrt{t^2+s^2}$ necciserily, so the addition generates an element not inside the supposed subspace.

Comment: where does the $\sqrt{t^2 + s^2}$ come from?

Comment: Check the last element and the definition.